# How to use logstash to parse structured json

Tags: json, logstash

Hi I'm a newbie to logstash. Currently I have some problems with parsing a structured json file like:

```html
data : {
  some_other_tag: [
    actual_data_1: {
      something......
    }
    actual_data_2: {
      something......
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I just want to take all of actual_data fields and indexing them with elasticsearch. How to do that?

My Logstash conf is like this right now:

```html
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      some_name => {
       url => "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      }
    }
    type => "some_type"
    request_timeout => 60
    interval => 60
    codec => json
  }
}

filter {
 /*what should I write here?*/
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "some_name"
  }
  stdout {
   codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

the stdout is like:

```html
{
timestamp : xxxxxxx
version : xxxxxxx
data : {
      some_other_tag: [
        actual_data_1: {
          something......
        }
        actual_data_2: {
          something......
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

What I want is:

```html
{
  actual_data1:{
    timestamp:xxxx
    version: xxx
    some data.....
  }
  actual_data2:{
    timestamp:xxxx
    version: xxx
    some data.....
  }
}
```

Comment: If 'actual_data1' and 'actual_data2' are constants, you might be able to use mutate->rename to move them up to the root level.  If that doesn't work, try mutate->add_field to copy them.  If the two values are dynamic, you'll need to drop into the ruby{} filter.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately they are dynamic. So I tried out ruby filter yesterday, it seems to be working so far. Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  You should answer your own question.